# Looping through Array dynamically in a Sandbox Solution

Tags: sandbox-solution

I have the following code

```
string[] listArray = new string[] {"some list", "Some other list"}
foreach (string s in listArray)
{
SPList listName = rootWeb.Lists[s];
}
```

Ok that should be enough to see whats going on, basically if i remove iCount from listArray[iCount] and replace it with a value then it works

If not I get the usual Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrappers Execute method which is the error you get when it doesn't work in the Sandbox.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you are using iCount at all?

Does this work:

```
foreach (string s in listArray)
{
    string listName = s;
}
```

Alternatively

```
string[] listArray = new string[] { "some list", "Some other list" };

int len = listArray.Count<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
     string listName = listArray[i];
}
```

Otherwise dump in a try/catch which may be manifesting itself as a Sandbox error. Arrays can often have null/empty values too so worth validating the contents of the item in the array.

Comment: Beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess i'm having a hard time even understanding why you need the icount.  I would think the code should look like this:

```
string[] listArray = new string[] {"some list", "Some other list"} 
foreach (string s in listArray) 
{ 
string listName = s;

}
```

Comment: OK yeah you're right on that front so I removed that and it still brings up the same error. So I will post the new code

Answer (score 0):

Aha... it may be relating to one of these:

1. Your list doesn't exist
2. You don't have permission to access it
3. rootWeb is null

Try/Catch with validation?

Comment: I am passing in the same value as if I do it explicitly, I have debugged it and the value does get passed in correctly but it still does not work in the sandbox.